# Load a controller if authorized

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

I am trying to load a controller (Dashboard) if session is ok.

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
    echo 'dashboard-01'; //test load
    $this->load->controllers('Dashboard');//Not sure if syntax is ok.
```

Is this possible? are there better approaches on how to do this?

Comment: You should look into HMVC for loading controllers with in controllers normal MVC cannot.

Comment: I had a look on wiki. Hierarchical model–view–controller is probably what I am doing here, without knowing about HMVC. I have a MVC for log in, and new MVC for the different parts of the application. Thank you @wolfgang1983 for this comment, I will definitely read more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is to load the controller and check on its constructor if the user has enough credentials:

```
class Sociedades extends CI_Controller {

    var $globales = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library(array('ion_auth','form_validation'));
        // Elliot, if you see this, don't delete it!
        $this->load->model('fSociety_model');

        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            //redirect them to the login page if not authorized
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    // then the index and other methods...
}
```

By the way, I'm using Ben Edmund's IonAuth.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. now is working... Gracias@zJorge.